# MacOS Mojave won't launch jar file

Tags: java, macos

I have a particular issue I can't seem to find an answer for, or rhyme/reason to why it's happening in the first place. I'm running the newest version of MacOS with Java up to date, but I have 1 particular JAR that won't open. I get the *The Java JAR file could not be launched. Check the console for possible error messages*

When I run the program from the console, it runs just fine so I have no idea what to do. I'm almost out of hair from pulling it out. What's going on?

-This is the only JAR file that has this issue. I have mutiple other JARs that run just fine.

-All Jars are developed from myself

-I compiled it in Eclipse, from 2 different computers and it's the same error BUT ONLY ON MY iMac. When I run it on my MacBook it runs fine.

Please help me - I'm desperate.

[image]

Comment: What do you think would be special about this JAR? Using any networking / security  features not present in the other ones?

Comment: Did you check the Console app? Paste the error messages here.

Comment: As the warning dialog instructs.. why don't you run the jar file in the console? That will give you the error message and more debugging tips on why that specific jar file does not run.

Comment: open terminal, execute `java -jar <your-jar-file>.jar`, and check what you are getting, or you can add some more logs to your code, rebuild jar and debug.

Comment: I changed the permissions on this JAR to rwx for everyone, so it's not a permission or security thing. I also ran the JAR in the console and it launches as expected, so no error message appears.

Answer (score 1):

It appears my workspace is somehow corrupted. When I made a new project and then copied+pasted all the source code over to this new project, then export it, it works just fine.